# "Many of my friends" vs "many friends"

Tags: grammar

I was writing a complaint to an Indian website and got confused between:

> I recommended your website to many of my friends

versus

> I recommended your website to my many friends

I am not a native English speaker, so please feel free to add points, alternate phrase to convey the same message or comment on my email writing.

Comment: Alternatively, you could simplify this to "*I recommended your site to many friends*".  You don't need a "*my*" at all.

Comment: One could have 200 friends on a popular social media site. I doubt that I'd call them my friends (yes, subtle distinction between my friends and friends that I have on a site) but my friends are slightly more personal than those which are one step away from simple acquaintances. On topic: @Tim's answer is about what I'd say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first
 one.

> I recommended your website to many of my friends

This means that a big proportion of your friends were recommended it. This is what you want.

> I recommended your website to my many friends

That means that you recommended it to all of your friends, and you have many friends. That comes across as you are very popular - bragging slightly.

Comment: I agree with the point being made about bragging. It sounded a bit arrogant to me when I read it.